# HTML file upload permission error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the HTML file upload to allow a user to upload a file, but I'm getting a NOT_READABLE_ERR file error while trying to read the file.

Here's my relevant HTML code:

```
<form onsubmit="print()">
  <input type="file" id="temp"></input>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
function print(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("temp");
  var file = elem.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(e){
    console.log(reader.error);
    console.log(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

The error that gets logged on console is a **NOT_READABLE_ERR**, which I found is "The file or directory cannot be read, typically due to permission problems that occur after a reference to a file has been acquired (for example, the file or directory is concurrently locked by another application)."

But I don't know how to fix this. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the file parsing function from the submit to an onchange on the file input:

```
<input type="file" id="temp" name="file1" onchange="print()"></input>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much :) Do you happen to know why it doesn't work on the submit?

Comment: cool. about not working on submit - looks like a design decision in the implementation.